# Printing half pyramid

Tags: c++, nested-loops

I want the pyramid to look like this if the input was 6

```
     0
    12
   345
  6789
 01234
567890
```

Here's my code

```
void HalfPyramid(int num)
{
    for (int a=0; a<num; a++)
    {
        for (int b=0; b<num-a; b++)
        {
        cout << " ";
        }
        for (int c=0; c<a; c++)
        {
            cout << a;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

I'm getting

```
     1
    22
   333
  4444
 55555
```

Not sure how to show the numbers as increasing throughout, I tried outputting `a` and `a+1`.

Comment: Doesn't print out the increasing numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another variable.  That variable needs to start at 0 and increment every time you print it.  Then since you need to to wrap back to 0 once you print 9 we will use the modulus operator to constrain the output to the range of [0, 9].  With all that you get

```
void HalfPyramid(int num)
{
    int output = 0;
    for (int a=1; a<num+1; a++)
    {
        for (int b=0; b<num-a; b++)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        for (int c=0; c<a; c++)
        {
            cout << output++ % 10;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void HalfPyramid(int num)
{
    int cur = 0;
        for (int a=0; a<num; a++)
        {
        for (int b = 1; b < num - a ; b++)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        for (int c=0; c < a + 1; c++)
        {
            cout << cur;
            cur = (cur+1)%10;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers already provide working versions of `HalfPyramid`. This answer, hopefully, makes you think of the logic and functionality a bit differently. I like to create small functions that capture the essence what I am trying to do rather than using the language to just do it.

```
bool isSpace(int num, int a, int b) 
{
   return ((a + b) < (num - 1));
}

int getNextDigit(int in)
{
   return (in+1)%10;
}

void HalfPyramid(int num)
{
   int digit = 0;
   for (int a = 0; a < num; ++a)
   {
      for (int b = 0; b < num; ++b)
      {
         if ( isSpace(num, a, b) )
         {
            cout << " ";
         }
         else
         {
            cout << digit;
            digit = getNextDigit(digit);
         }
      }
      cout << endl;
   }
}
```